# Is it impossible to call a scala package function from a java file?

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

For example, scala.concurrent.promise

What's the best general workaround for such cases if not? Defining a utility object/class in scala that dispatches to the package function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class with the name `package` is created, with the relevant methods as static members. In this case, you would need to invoke `scala.concurrent.package.promise` from Java.

However, `scala.concurrent.promise` is deprecated, use `scala.concurrent.Promise.apply` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the deprecation. I still can't execute this from java code. I tried "import scala.concurrent.Promise; ... Promise<Foo> p = Promise.<Foo>apply();" to no avail. This is not surprising since eclipse is reporting Promise to be an interface. Do you know how to instantiate a Promise in java?

Comment: Try `import scala.concurrent.Promise; import scala.concurrent.Promise$; ... Promise<Foo> p = Promise$.MODULE$.<Foo>apply()`. Interfaces can't have static methods, so Scala can't generate the static forwarders for companion objects of traits like it can for classes.

Comment: I get "The import scala.concurrent.Promise$ cannot be resolved" (java 7 and scala 2.11). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure. It worked for me, with the same versions.

Comment: Figured out the problem. I had to run mvn compile from the command line first for some reason before eclipse would recognize the import. I guess this occurred because the Promise$ class file needs to be generated for use in java (just guessing)? Do you know why I would have needed to run mvn compile for the import to resolve as opposed to just a simple eclipse build (running with m2e and m2e-scala plugins)? Thanks.

Comment: Promise$.class was always there in scala-library.jar, so the only explanation is it's some problem with Eclipse, though I can't explain it beyond that.